# getting error for argument order disorder in a python program

Tags: python

When I run the following code get error as follows:

```
 trip_cost should take exactly three parameters: city, days, and spending_money (in that order).
```

The following code have the same order of argument as said. But still getting the same error even that its returning the trip cost as 1995.

```
def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
       return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220

    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif city == "LosAngeles":
        return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost = 40 
    if days >= 7:
        return (cost * days - 50)
    elif days >= 3 < 7:
        return (cost * days - 20)
    elif days < 3:
        return (cost * days)

def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140 * nights

def money(spending_money):
    return spending_money

def trip_cost(city,days,spending_money):

    total_trip_cost = plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_car_cost(days) + hotel_cost(days) + money(spending_money)
    return total_trip_cost

print trip_cost("LosAngeles",5,600)
```

Comment: Its working fine for me. I got `1955` as result.

Comment: How are you running that code?

Comment: yes i have been coding in the codecademy.com and there is some issue with the online compiler they have made. But can't I move ahead till I don't finish it.

Comment: Reload the page. Or visit the forum link from the codecademy page to find a workaround.

Comment: try `trip_cost(city="LosAngeles",days=5,spending_money=600)`

Comment: This website does not have fourm support

Comment: Codecademy *does* have forum support

Comment: Sidenote: The second condition in `rental_car_cost()` is wrong.  It doesn't make a difference but the `< 7` part of the test is effectively a null operation because 3 is _always_ smaller than 7 so that part of the test is _always_ true.